# biblatex philosophy-modern separating book/article from the same author

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-philosophy

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrarticle}
\usepackage{filecontents}  
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}  
%
@book{schaefer:bl,
    Author = {Helmut H. Schaefer},
    Keywords = {Schaefer},
    Publisher = {Springer},
    Title = {Banach Lattices and Positive Operators},
    Year = {1974}}
%
@article{schaefer:1967,
    Author = {Schaefer, H. H.},
    Journal = {Illinois J. Math.},   
    Pages = {703--715},
    Title = {Invariant ideals of positive operators in $C(X)$ (I)},
    Volume = {11},
    Year = {1967}}
%
\end{filecontents}  
\usepackage[%
    ,backend=biber
    ,style=philosophy-modern
    ,firstinits = true]{biblatex}  
%
\bibliography{mybib}      
\begin{document}  
%
\nocite{*}  
\printbibliography      
\end{document}
```

which produces
[image: output of mwe]

But both, book and article should be not separated. I looked into the User's Guide without success.

Comment: The `author` fields of the two entries in your `.bib` file are not identical. One contains the full first name, the other just the initial.

Comment: Ups, beginners mistake. Thanks.

Comment: @leandriis Do you want to type up a quick answer here?

Comment: @moewe: Thanks for reminding me, I have just added an answer. I hope I dind't overlook something there.

Comment: @Ulrich If the answer below answered your question, please consider upvoting and accepting it (cf. also https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If it does not resolve your problem (even though I read your comment above suggesting it did), it would be great if you could leave a small comment explaining why. (In this case it would be conceivable that you insist on `biblatex` listing the works under the same name because the output of the names [though different in the `.bib`] is the same in the document.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `author` fields of the two bib entries are not identical (the first one contains the full first name, while the second one only contains the initial), they are treated as two different authors.

If you homogenize the `author` fields as shown in the below MWE, you get the desired result with both references listed below the same name:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrarticle}
% \usepackage{filecontents}% not needed any more since fall 2019 since the functionality was integrated into the latex kernel
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}  
%
@book{schaefer:bl,
%    Author = {Helmut. H. Schaefer},
    Author = {H. H. Schaefer},
    Keywords = {Schaefer},
    Publisher = {Springer},
    Title = {Banach Lattices and Positive Operators},
    Year = {1974}}
%
@article{schaefer:1967,
    Author = {Schaefer, H. H.},
    Journal = {Illinois J. Math.},   
    Pages = {703--715},
    Title = {Invariant ideals of positive operators in $C(X)$ (I)},
    Volume = {11},
    Year = {1967}}
%
\end{filecontents}  
\usepackage[%
    ,backend=biber
    ,style=philosophy-modern
    ,giveninits = true]{biblatex}  % firstinits is deprecated and was replaced with giveninits in version 3.3 (2016-03-01), see corresponding warning
%
\bibliography{mybib}      
\begin{document}  
%
\nocite{*}  
\printbibliography      
\end{document}
```

In the above MWE, I have added some comments regarding the `firstinits` option of `biblatex` that was replaced with `giveninits` and the `filecontents` package that was incorporated into the latex kernel. You might want to adapt your document code accordingly.